# How can I display my var array name in HTML textblock?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display my var array names in a textblock. These need to change depending on what box is ticked in my form.

Now I can show the values in the array, but I need to display the actual name too. I am VERY new to coding, and I have trouble finding the right words to describe my problem, thus not finding any solution. I hope you can help me out.

```
var color_prices = new Array();
color_prices["Orange"]=1;
color_prices["Blue"]=2;
color_prices["Green"]=3;

function getColorPrice()
{
    var ColorPrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["order-form"];

    var selectedColor = theForm.elements["COLOR"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedColor.length; i++)
    {
        if(selectedColor[i].checked)
        {

            ColorPrice = color_prices[selectedColor[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }
    return ColorPrice;
}

var colorPrice = getColorPrice();

document.getElementById('colorPrice').innerHTML = colorPrice.toFixed(2);
```

Right now I 'stole' some code online to display the value of "orange" in my html (so "1") and this works but I have no idea how to display the value "orange" in my html.

I hope I explained it correctly.

Comment: have you tried `color_prices[selectedColor[i].label]`?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of your html code?

Comment: Those are called "keys" and you can convert them into a new array with `var color_keys = Object.keys(color_prices);`. Now `color_keys` will contain `['Orange','Blue','Green']`. After that you can get the values out of the `color_keys` array just like you're already doing.

Comment: @Cyval  where would I add this? 


€<span id="colorPrice"></span>   that is actually the only piece of code that now shows the price in my HTML.

Comment: What HTML? Post it if it's relevant. Obviously it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to change your `ColorPrice` variable to be an object to be able to store the color price and the color name, in my example I'm also changing the name of the variable to `colorDetails` to be more descriptive about what is containing

```
var color_prices = new Array();
color_prices["Orange"]=1;
color_prices["Blue"]=2;
color_prices["Green"]=3;

function getColorDetails()
{
    //here we rename the variable and convert from integer to object
    var colorDetails = {
                         price: 0,
                         name: undefined
                        };

    var theForm = document.forms["order-form"];

    var selectedColor = theForm.elements["COLOR"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedColor.length; i++)
    {
        if(selectedColor[i].checked)
        {
            //here we store the color price inside colorDetails
            colorDetails.price = color_prices[selectedColor[i].value];
            //and we add this new line where we save the name of the color
            colorDetails.name = selectedColor[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    return colorDetails;
}

var colorDetails = getColorDetails();

document.getElementById('colorPrice').innerHTML = colorDetails.name + ": " + colorDetails.price.toFixed(2);
```